# Best way to compute statistics for 'average' upper and lower values of cyclic data like a refrigerated cooler

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I have lots of temperature data and when plotted it shows events like door open for a while and the repetitive cycling of the compressor every few minutes. I would like to calculate means for compressor on/off states that are immune from skewing from the door open. In the graph below it appears that the compressor OFF mean is about 40.0  and the Compressor ON mean is about 38.5 ( ignoring the big spike that is an outlier)

I suspect I need multiple methods to massage the data to get my two results of 'high mean' and 'low mean' ( my made-up terms). Perhaps a IQR to find and throw away the outlier(s) and some kind of windowing to find  & group the local upper and lower peaks into sets to  average.

I am coding in Python so I can use any Python library or try to roll my own.

Any ideas how to do this?

[image]

Comment: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/3/3.2#:~:text=Any%20observations%20that%20are%20more,to%20identify%20outliers%20by%20default.  "The interquartile range is often used to find outliers in data. Outliers here are defined as observations that fall below Q1 − 1.5 IQR or above Q3 + 1.5 IQR."

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are not interested in the data that is generated when the door opens, correct? If that's the case, there is a bunch of possible solutions.

#### Drop the outliers

By dropping the outliers you can still use the regular mean.

#### Use median instead of the mean

If you don't want to drop the values you could switch to calculating the median, which is generally not affected by outliers.

#### Use rolling means

Rolling means usually are not highly affected by variations in the data like the one you show in your chart. And you can also change the time frame for the rolling mean.([Pandas - Rolling Mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html))

#### Apply normalization

Normalization scales down the variation in the data, but there is a lot of normalization techniques, so you'd need to find the one that best fits your case. ([sklearn - normalization](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html))

Hope this was helpful

Comment: Median does not really help - I need to find the averages of max and min of the sawtooth waveform. Rolling max | min could work but I would need to adjust the window size somehow for each different system. I may just try to write my own code. Won't know if it is fast enough for production until I try!